# Excel: Count all cells that have doubled (Chinese) characters within the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, chinese-locale, vba

I have a list of a few thousand Chinese brand names, one brand name per cell, and I'm trying to count how many of those names use doubled characters, meaning two of the same Chinese characters one after another. For example, here's a list of 6 brand names (each one would be in its own cell):

1. 水晶晶
2. 衣二三
3. 五五
4. 淘宝
5. 哈哈哇
6. 拉啪拉

Numbers 1, 3 and 5 have doubled characters in them (晶晶 , 五五, 哈哈), so I would like a formula that returns the number “3”, because there are three cells that contain doubled characters. (Note that although #6 contains two of the same characters - 拉, twice - those characters are not next to each other, and therefore wouldn't return as true).

I presume the fact that the characters are Chinese doesn't really matter, the formula would be the same for counting doubled letters, like：

ABB
CC
FDDF

Characters are not separated by a space. I don't know VBA, but happy to learn how to input and run a script.

Comment: You say `For example, I'd want to return: 水晶晶 ` .  What data are you returning that _from_?  If the input data is `AABBCDDD` then what should be returned.  More information will be needed, please [edit] your original question.

Comment: Edited! Hope that's enough info.

Comment: Okay, that's simpler than it first sounded... Is your list of names in a single row/column?

Comment: Yup, everything's in a single column.

Comment: Perfect.  Do you have experience with Excel?  Once the code is in your workbook, you'll be able to use the custom functions in cells just like the built-in functions.  Check it out and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hey, awesome! Thank you! I'm actually a front-end designer, but Excel is definitely not my thing, almost never use it. I'll check it out!

Comment: Wow - most questions I answer on SO are from a _"slightly less tech-savvy demographic"_ (not that there's anything wrong with that; everyone's gotta start somewhere!) but now that I've snooped your profile & impressive portfolio, I'm a little embarrassed: a hottie living in an exotic place **and** a FE dev?  Figures that you're the one who _doesn't_ need a hand held through the process... :-( Data's my thing, FE dev is scary & confusing. I recently spent days trying to decide on a color scheme for a pet project. :-) Let me know if you need further help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to discourage you from learning VBA (it's a great skill to have!) but I figured I'd whip up a VBA Function that you can start using with your data right away...  Once we confirm that everything's working I'll give you some links to explain how this (simple) function works, along with some other good beginners' resources.  :)

I have *never* worked with Chinese characters but I did a bit of research.  Western alphabets generally come from a set of 255 characters called ASCII.  Eastern alphabets come from a set of 65533 characters called Unicode.  ASCII characters each take 1 byte of storage space, whereas Unicode characters take up 2 bytes each.

What does this mean to a text function like the one I put together?  I'm not entirely sure!  Apparently I am supposed to use different builtin formulae than I normally would, but my code wouldn't work with the alternate method, yet seems to work just fine the way I've always done things.

This may be different with your "complete" data-set, combined with your computer's language settings compared to North America.  Theoretically, it should work just fine, but I'd suggest that when you start using it, count a bunch of different cells *manually* so that you can compare the numbers that the function gives you, and let me know if there are discrepancies.  (If you're list isn't "top secret", I'd kind of like to have a copy if you wouldn't mind; this is all foreign to me [pun intended] and I'd like to understand more about the differences data-wise.)

A small group of Chinese characters are not part of the Unicode standard yet, but apparently they are rarely used anyways (usually for place names?) but you should keep an eye on that.  Again, it shouldn't be an issue - in theory - because suspect that "if they aren't in Unicode, your computer won't have them either" (I think!)  [Here is a link to a list](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Chinese_characters_not_in_Unicode) of characters in question.

**Anyhow**, the only way to find out if it's working like it should is to **try it out** with your full set of data!

---

### How to copy the VBA functions into a module:

1. Select the VBA Code below, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.
2. Go to your Excel workbook, and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA Editor (aka *VBE*).
3. Click the **Insert** menu in the VBE, and choose **Module**.
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the code.
5. Click the **Debug** menu in the VBE, and choose **Compile Project".
   This checks the code for errors.  Ideally *"nothing"* will happen, meaning it's error-free & good to go.
6. Close the VBE window with the " **✘** " in the top-right corner.
7. Save your workbook, and the new functions are ready to use!
   See the screenshot below for example usage.

.

```
Public Function cellHasDups(str_In As String) As Boolean
'returns TRUE if there are at least 2 identical characters in a row

    Dim x As Integer, prevChar As String, dupFound As Boolean
    On Error GoTo dError

    prevChar = ""
    dupFound = False

    For x = 1 To Len(str_In) 'compare each character to the previous
        If Mid(str_In, x, 1) = prevChar Then dupFound = True
        prevChar = Mid(str_In, x, 1)
    Next x

    cellHasDups = dupFound 'return T/F to the calling cell
    Exit Function

dError:
    cellHasDups = False
End Function


Public Function rangeHasDups(rge_In As Range) As Long
'returns the number of cells in the specified range that have duplicate characters
'ashleedawg@outlook.com

    Dim c As Range, countDups As Long

    On Error GoTo dError

    countDups = 0
    'loop through all cells in selected range; run [cellHasDups] on each one and count "TRUE" responses
    For Each c In rge_In
        countDups = countDups + IIf(cellHasDups(c.Value), 1, 0)
    Next c

    rangeHasDups = countDups 'return total to the calling cell
    Exit Function

dError:
    rangeHasDups = 0
End Function
```

The function has 2 variations. You can paste them both into a module, and use whichever one one that suits your needs (or if there is another way that would be easier, I can make changes easily at this point):

- **cellHasDups** checks an individual cell and returns TRUE if the cell has 2 identical characters in a row, otherwise returns FALSE.
- **rangeHasDups** checks an rane of cells (ie, A1:A20 or A5:G99 or A:A etc) and returns a Count of cells which have duplicate characters.

[image: ChineseDuplicateTest screen shot]

Give it a try, and let me know if you have any issues or questions!

Comment: ...any luck? :)

Comment: YES! Works like a charm! You're brilliant! Thank you so much for that insane expenditure of effort.

Comment: Wasn't a major effort at all, plus it was an interesting excuse for me to introduce myself to 2-byte "foreign" characters.  Have you had a chance to try it out?  I'm really curious if it will work as it's supposed to.  Without a full set of data, I was kind of flying blind, but if you have an issue, I have a pretty good idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this macro to achieve this:

```
Sub countDoubles()

Dim Rrng As Range
Dim Rcell As Range
Dim cellArray(1 To 100) As Integer  //100 - The number of cells in the range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim count As Integer

On Error Resume Next
Set Rrng = Range("G10:G20")   //change this to the relevant range
j = 1

For Each Rcell In Rrng.Cells
    For i = 2 To Len(Rcell)
        If Mid(Rcell, i - 1, 1) = Mid(Rcell, i, 1) Then
            cellArray(j) = 1
            j = j + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next Rcell

For i = 1 To UBound(cellArray)
    count = count + cellArray(i)
    Next i
MsgBox (count)   //message box to show the number of double
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see point in using `cellArray`. You can count cells in first loop.

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted, just because of arrays? Using Arrays is a Good Practice and people that program on another languages are often used to arrays.